# How illegal is drug planting?

Tags: nevada

Let's say you leave fake drugs in someone's yard. Eg, you expect the police  to be dumb  enough to believe it and arrest the other person, but if caught, you can show they are obviously fake.

What crimes have I committed? Is it just trespassing? Isnt there any crime for planting fake evidence?

Comment: The title of this question has absolutely nothing to do with the body of it.

Comment: @Nij I think the OP means plant as in planting evidence, not as in growing drugs

Comment: But they're not planting drugs. They're putting something supposedly legitimate to possess. *Is it illegal to plant drugs?"* and *"Is it illegal to fake a crime?"* have overlapping but not identical answers.

Answer (score 3):

> Let's say you leave fake drugs in someone's yard. Eg, you expect the police to be dumb enough to believe it and arrest the other person

1. [Obstructing a public officer](https://www.shouselaw.com/nevada/obstructing-public-officer.html), specifically "deliberately hindering a public officer from carrying out official duties".
2. Trespassing.

Answer (score 1):

Many US states have an "Obstruction of Justice" statute (also known in common law as "perverting the course of justice"), which in many cases is broad enough to cover your scenario - the planting of an item intended to pervert the course of justice or obstruct an officer of the law during investigations:

> The crime can take any number of forms, whether it's bribery, ***tampering with evidence***, lying to investigators, abusing one's power, or some other act intended to impede a criminal investigation.

https://criminal.findlaw.com/criminal-charges/obstruction-of-justice.html

There is also a Federal statute for obstruction, so you may find yourself on a very wrong end of a very big stick.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the obstruction of justice or interference with a pubic officer mentioned in other answers, the ploy is unlikely to result in inconvenience to the occupier of the property unless it is reported to the police. So the process of reporting the fake drugs is likely to be [filing a false police report](https://criminal.findlaw.com/criminal-charges/filing-a-false-police-report.html), which could be prosecuted if the person filing the report is caught.